# Convert date in format yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss to epoch

Tags: javascript, node.js

I running node.js

I am trying to convert the time to epoch, but it says that "TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined"

My input string

"216397470, 2020-10-10 10:12:14, lora-test, iotoyster, 313532352A004100, LORA, SF10BW125, 10.50, -86.00, 868.100, 33, -29.757551, 30.789891, -18.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0, null, null

```js
var output = msg.payload.split(",");

var tag1 = "gps";
var tag2 = output[2];
var tag3 = output[3];

var time = output[1];


var match = time.match(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+)$/)
var date = new Date(match[1], match[2] - 1, match[3], match[4], match[5], match[6])

var counter = output[0];
var alt =  output[13];
var hdop = output[15];
var headingDeg = 0;
var latitude = output[11];
var longitude = output[12];
var speed = output[7];


msg.payload = [{
    counter: counter,
    alt : output[13],
    hdop: output[15],
    headingDeg: headingDeg,
    latitude: output[11],
    longitude: output[12],
    speed: 300,
    time: date
},
{
    tag1: tag1,
    tag2: tag2,
    tag3: tag3,
}];
return msg;
```

Comment: try `time.trim().match(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible to transform your date format to a normal Date javascript Object format, you could maybe use this example above:

```
var myDate = new Date("July 1, 1978 02:30:00"); // Your timezone!
var myEpoch = myDate.getTime()/1000.0;
document.write(myEpoch);
```

More info here: [Epoch Converter Functions](https://www.epochconverter.com/programming/#javascript)

Sorry if i missunderstood your question. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Your `split(",")` is returning a preceding   (space) for `output[1]`

```
var time = output[1];
=> " 2020-10-10 10:12:14"
    ^
```

This is causing your regex match to fail:

```
var match = time.match(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+)$/)
=> null
```

You can `trim` it first:

```
var match = time.trim().match(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+)$/)
=> Array(7) [ "2020-10-10 10:12:14", "2020", "10", "10", "10", "12", "14" ]
```

Now this will run:

```
var date = new Date(match[1], match[2] - 1, match[3], match[4], match[5], match[6])
```

Though you could use this to get the epoch:

```
var date = Date.parse(match[1], match[2] - 1, match[3], match[4], match[5], match[6])
=> 1577836800000
```

Comment: Can you please score my question? As you answer did help me and the system have now blocked me as the AI perceives I am not contributing.